# Error "can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple" when adding heroku line

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my project, but when I try to compile with the "django_heroku.settings (locals ())" line to my settings.py, it returns the following error:

```
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/anderson.maronato/Desktop/proj/django-finale/choiceshoes/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/anderson.maronato/Desktop/proj/django-finale/choiceshoes/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/anderson.maronato/Desktop/proj/django-finale/choiceshoes/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/anderson.maronato/Desktop/proj/django-finale/choiceshoes/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/anderson.maronato/Desktop/proj/django-finale/choiceshoes/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/anderson.maronato/Desktop/proj/cc2/choiceshoes/djecommerce/settings/development.py", line 10, in <module>
    MIDDLEWARE += ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', ]
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple
```

My Settings.py with the configuration

```
import os
from decouple import config
import django_heroku

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_countries',

    'core'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djecommerce.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djecommerce.wsgi.application'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Auth

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend'
)
SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'


django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

In the terminal inside heroku the same tuple error appears. Without the `django_heroku.settings(locals())` line, it works.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: out of curosity, in your ```djecommerce/settings/development.py``` file, on line 10, it says ```MIDDLEWARE + [...]```.   What is ```MIDDLEWARE```?

Comment: Is a framework of hooks into Django’s request/response processing

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and in my case it was due to the fact that my Django app had been generated by `cookiecutter-django`, with which the settings are factored in a submodule with many files (e.g. `settings/base.py`, `settings/local.py`, etc.) rather than in a single `settings.py` as it would be typically. So in such a setup (which I suspect is somehow your case, because even if your question is formulated in terms of a single `settings.py` file, your stack trace on top shows that you have a `settings/development.py` file), if the `django_heroku.settings(locals())` invocation is not at the very end (i.e. of the last module imported) you might have this particular problem because `django-heroku` effectively coerces `MIDDLEWARE` into a `tuple`, after having injected its stuff in it, as is clear if you look at its code:

https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku/blob/master/django_heroku/core.py#L105

I don't know what is the rationale for that type conversion, but it is clearly the cause of your problem (and the solution is to have the invocation at the very end like they recommend).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`MIDDLEWARE += [ # Debugger toolbar (the order is important) 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', ]`

with
`MIDDLEWARE += ( # Debugger toolbar (the order is important) 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', )`
in settings/development.py